# Displaying ToolTip on AHK Script Start Up and Permanently

Tags: autohotkey

I am using ToolTip to show tool tip at start up but it somehow doesn't show at all.

I've tried #Persistent but that also doesn't seem to help.

```
InformEnabled() {
    ToolTip, HotKeys Enabled
    return
}

InformDisabled() {
    ToolTip
    return
}

InformEnabled()
SetTimer, InformDisabled, -1000
```

I have a script as can be seen in the code.

The above snippet doesn't show the initially intended tool tip.
Is it because the main script thread is terminating or something like that?
How can I display tool tip at the start of the script?

Comment: Did you put the above snippet in the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (top of the script)?

Comment: Nope, I put it at the end, and not at the top of the script. That was the problem! Please add this as the answer and I will mark it so. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any lines you want to execute immediately when the script starts should appear at the top of the script, prior to the first hotkey, hotstring, or Return.

This section of the script is executed ONCE, immediately after loading the script.

```
#NoEnv
; ...

InformEnabled()
SetTimer, InformDisabled, -1000

; ...

        RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

; ...

InformEnabled() {
    ToolTip, HotKeys Enabled
    return
}

InformDisabled() {
    ToolTip
    return
}
```

For details, see [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).